# extension of Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis

I want to show $\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}b_{i,j}$<=$\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}\sum_{i,j}b_{i,j}$, can I use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality to do that? Or is there any conditions needed to show the inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will index the functions as $a_i,b_i$ which is equivalent. We have by triangle inequality, followed by Cauchy-Schwartz on $\ell^2$, followed by the embedding $\ell^2\subset\ell^1$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_ia_ib_i&\leq\sum_i|a_ib_i|\\
&\leq\left(\sum_ia_i^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_ib_i^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\left(\sum_i|a_i|\right)\left(\sum_i|b_i|\right).
\end{align*}
I believe this is the closest you can get to your desired inequality. This holds as long as $a_i,b_i$ are complex sequences indexed by $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Z$. Note that if they are not in $\ell^1$ this might hold in the sense that $\infty\leq\infty$.

Also observe that the inequality you wrote without the absolute values is not true; for instance let $a=b=(1,-1,0,0,0,\ldots)$. However if $a,b$ are assumed to be nonnegative then what you wrote is true.